# Salesforce error: Too many code statements 200001

Tags: apex-code

I have created an opportunity trigger to send out an email to two separate email address field whenever the stage is Closed Won depending on the Campaign Type. It works perfectly fine but recently when I tried updating a list of 200 opportunity records it gave me an error saying "**Too many code statements 200001**".

My code is as follows:

```
trigger SendEmail on Opportunity (after update)
{
        Set<Id> accountSet = new Set<Id>();
        Set<Id> marketSet = new Set<Id>();

        for (Opportunity o : Trigger.new) {
        accountSet.add(o.Accountid);
        marketSet.add(o.Campaignid);
        }
        Map<Id, Account> accountMap = new Map<Id, Account>([SELECT Name, Phone, PersonMobilePhone, PersonEmail  from Account where id in :accountSet] );
        map<Id, Campaign> marketMap = new Map<Id, Campaign>([SELECT Name, Parent_Market__c from Campaign where id in :marketSet]); 
        for (Opportunity o : Trigger.new) {
           if(o.Campaign_Type__c != Null && o.StageName != Null){
           for (Integer i = 0; i < Trigger.old.size(); i++) {
           Opportunity old = Trigger.old[i];
           Opportunity nw = Trigger.new[i];
           Account theAccount = accountMap.get(o.AccountId);
           Campaign Market = marketMap.get(o.CampaignId);
           String userName = UserInfo.getUserName();

            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();                   
            List<String> toAddresses = new List<String>();
            List<String> ccAddresses = new List<String>();
            ccAddresses.add('test@test.com');
            mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);       
            mail.setCcAddresses(ccAddresses);
            mail.setSenderDisplayName('Campaign Information');

            mail.setSubject(+ theAccount.Name + ' is Closed Won');

            mail.setReplyTo('noreply@salesforce.com');
            //Body of the Email
            mail.setHtmlBody(
               '<font face="Times" size="3">'+
               '<table width="100%">'+
               '<tr width="0%">'+
               '<td rowspan="0">'+
              '</td>'+
               '<td>'+
               '<h2>Account is closed won notification</h2>'+
               '</td>'+
               '</tr>'+
               '</table>'+
               '<br/>'+
               '<b>Stage:</b> ' + o.StageName + '<br/>' + '<br/>' +
               '<b>Opportunity Number:</b> ' + o.Name + '<br/>' +
               '<b>Amount Paid:</b> $' + o.Amount + '<br/>' + '<br/>' +
               '<b>Account Name:</b> ' + theAccount.Name + '<br/>' +
               '<b>Phone:</b> ' + theAccount.Phone + '<br/>' +
               '<b>Mobile:</b> ' + theAccount.PersonMobilePhone + '<br/>'+
               '<b>Email:</b> ' + theAccount.PersonEmail + '<br/>'+
               );

          // Send Email if it isCampaign1 and Closed Won
          if((nw.StageName !=old.StageName) || (nw.Campaign_Type__c !=old.Campaign_Type__c)){               
            if(o.Campaign_Type__c.equals('Campaign1')){
                if(o.StageName.equals('Closed Won') ){
                toAddresses.add(o.Email__c);
                try {
                Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
                }
                catch(Exception ex) { }
                }

            }
          }
          // Send Email if it is Campaign2 and Closed Won
          if((nw.StageName !=old.StageName) || (nw.Campaign_Type__c !=old.Campaign_Type__c)){     
            if(o.Campaign_Type__c.equals('Campaign2')){
              if(o.StageName.equals('Closed Won')){
                 toAddresses.add(o.Email2__c);
                 toAddresses.add(o.Email1__c);
                try {
                Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
                }
                catch(Exception ex) { }
                }
            }
          }    
            }   
       }
       }     
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Try to hide composing an e-mail object under opp's check. Compose an e-mail only if you will send it, but not for every opp.

Comment: Also, you can pull Opps by SOQL which have (o.Campaign_Type__c != Null && o.StageName != Null), so you won't need this check at all in your for loop.

Comment: Remove for loop with Trigger.old. Use Opportunity old = Trigger.old.get(o.Id); as Shimshon Korits proposed.

Answer (score 0):

Why you sand for each opportunity Trigger.new.size() emails?
your code degree is n*n.

Change

```
for (Opportunity o : Trigger.new) {
           if(o.Campaign_Type__c != Null && o.StageName != Null){
           for (Integer i = 0; i < Trigger.old.size(); i++) {
           Opportunity old = Trigger.old[i];
           Opportunity nw = Trigger.new[i];
```

To something like

```
 for (Opportunity o : Trigger.new) {
                   if(o.Campaign_Type__c != Null && o.StageName != Null){
                   Opportunity old = Trigger.old.get(o.Id);
                   Opportunity nw = o;
                   if(((nw.StageName !=old.StageName) || (nw.Campaign_Type__c !=old.Campaign_Type__c)) && (nw.StageName.equals('Closed Won')&&((nw.Campaign_Type__c.equals('Campaign1')||(nw.Campaign_Type__c.equals('Campaign2')){
              .......................
```

Comment: Thank you Chiz and Shimshonfor your response. @Shimshonfor I changed my code to what you have mentioned. It works well but as I said I need to send out emails to two different email ids, Email__c if Campaign type is Campaign1 and Email1__c and Email2__c if Campaign type is Campaign2. Now I am not able to achieve that. It only sends the email to the ccaddresses and not to the toAddresses.